# How to include dependencies in J2V8

Tags: node.js, v8, j2v8

How to include dependencies in J2V8? I would like to use certain dependencies in the javascript file for instance the crypto package.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function foo(){ return crypto.createHash('md5').update('Apple').digest("hex");}
```

However, I got the following error saying `require` keyword is undefined.

```
undefined:1: ReferenceError: require is not defined

var crypto = require('crypto');
         ^
 ReferenceError: require is not defined at <anonymous>:1:14
  com.eclipsesource.v8.V8ScriptExecutionException
at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8._executeVoidScript(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me how to import an package into J2V8?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope. i eventually gave up the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working with Node, `require` is not a feature. Usually, you want to use a bundler like webpack to pack your structured source code into one large file so that it can be understood by browsers. This way you can use require and npm packages for your frontend code, which makes development easier, and a bundler turns it with every build (or live update) into a different format, that's hard to read for humans, but is valid Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using node modules in J2v8, please check out this blog :http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/07/20/running-node-js-on-the-jvm/

NodeJs nodeJS = NodeJs.createNodeJs();

After registering callbacks

nodeJs.exec(File thescripttoexecute)

Make sure you have the proper path to the node modules in the require() command.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to make a nodejs package that takes dependencies and exports what you need. Then, You have to execute `npm install` manually.

or You can just `npm install what-you-need`.

Create Node JS Runtime, and use require with your `your-package-dir/index.js` or exact location of module that you need. like this:

```
V8Object module = nvm.require(file);
```

Now you can call the function likes:

```
module.executeJSFunction("test");
```

To deliver entire dependencies you have to bundlize module directory your self.

What if you have to support cross-platform, refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp also.